# How many positive integers $N \le 10^6$ such that $\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor|N$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> How many positive integers $N \le 10^6$ such that $N$ divided by $\lfloor \sqrt N \rfloor$?

*I do not know how to solve this problem without a computer.*

Comment: Why? If $N=20$, then $\lfloor \sqrt20\rfloor=4$. And $4|20$

Comment: ooooops, right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a=\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor$. We have
$$a^2\le N<a^2+2a+1$$

Suppose that $a\mid N$. Then
$$a\le\frac Na< a+2+\frac1a$$
So $N/a$ must be $a$, $a+1$ or $a+2$.

Therefore, the numbers that hold the statement are:

- The perfect squares
- The numbers of the form $a(a+1)$
- The numbers of the form $a(a+2)$

So you should solve these inequalitites:
$$a^2\le 10^6$$
$$a(a+1)\le10^6$$
$$a(a+2)\le10^6$$

Note that these three sets of numbers (that is, the perfect squares, the numbers of the form $a(a+1)$ and the numbers of the form $a(a+2)$) are disjoint. (Why?)

Answer (score 5):

Let $m=\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$.  Then $m^2\leq N\leq m^2+2m$ and $N$ is a multiple of $m$.